# Interview for J-2 Visa issuance (USA)

Tags: usa, visa

I have a J-1 Visa for an exchange program in the USA. I'm a European Union Citizen.

I have a girlfriend and we may plan to get married in the future. If that happens, she's going to apply for a J-2 Visa.

Now, here comes my question. She does not speak english, at all. I know of people that have been denied a J-1 for their mediocre english, not good enough to communicate in the United States. But what about a J-2? Is the interview going to be in english? There is no way my girlfriend (or future wife) will be able to answer the consular officer questions, as simple these questions may be. In such case, is she going to be denied the J-2 Visa?

Comment: How far in the future might you plan to marry? Can your GF improve her English in the interim, assuming a certain level of command of the language is in fact necessary at the application stage after the marriage has taken place?

Comment: If some english is actually required at the J-2 interview, I'd say she's going to need one year at least, unless she attends some very, very intensive course.

Comment: A J2 visa holder is dependent on the J1 status. Therefore, I don't believe that they would require her to speak english. However, I do agree that it would be extremely beneficial for her to learn so she's able to apply for the visa and survive and the U.S.